# Should we create [google-people] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

Google has given their official [People API](https://developers.google.com/people) discussion tag as [google-people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people).

But I can't post my question with that tag. The tag is not showing up for me.
Since I don't have 1500 reputation, I can't create the tag too.

Here is my question without tag: [Get contact email addresses using Google People API in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717624/get-contact-email-addresses-using-google-people-api-in-javascript)

Comment: Post the question without the tag and leave the link here, someone will take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the tag [google-people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people) to your question.

Feel free to [suggest an tag wiki / excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/118184).

Comment: I foresee somebody using the tag to force people to Google or to find out more about Google devs (Mr.Skeet, for example) :P . Maybe [tag:google-people-api] is better.