# What should we do with [google-contacts-api] (deprecated and retired)?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) and [google-people-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people-api)

The first was used on questions about a Google API and Google Apps Script Service (Class ContactsApp) that are now **deprecated and retired** but also on questions about **Google Contacts**, the cross-platform app linked to Gmail and other Google cross-platform apps.

These tags should not be made synonyms because the code used with Contacts API doesn't work with the People API; **it's required to migrate**.

[The page about Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts?hl=en_US) now points to [the Contacts API **migration** to the People API page](https://developers.google.com/people/contacts-api-migration) hosted on the People API microsite on https://developers.google.com.

One of the "problems" with [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) is that it's being added by "default" in questions related to handling contacts on Google Contacts and other Google apps.

- Should we edit the [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) excerpt to add something like "DO NOT USE ON NEW QUESTIONS"?
- Is it possible / a good idea to add a tag warning to be applied to all new questions, considering that the Google Contacts API is deprecated and retired?

---

Note:

This is a "Google" classic. Not too long ago, we have [Should we merge Google Hangouts tags with Google Chat?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423317/1595451).

The case depicted in this question differs from the Hangouts / Chat case because it is not about having two brands and two tags. In this case, only one consumer app matches one of the API names, Google Contacts, and also matches the name of the entity / record type used on Gmail and other apps: contact.

Another important difference is that in the previous post, some code still works, but the code using the Contact API doesn't work anymore.

Related

- [Should we create [google-people] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317975/1595451)
- [Renaming request: [googlecontactsapi] to [google-contacts-api]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385746/1595451)
- [Should questions with tag [contacts] be retagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387643/1595451)
- [Merge [google-people] and [google-people-api]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411112/1595451)

Comment: What do you mean by being added by "default"? No tags are defaulted.

Comment: @ThomA [tag:google-contacts-api] might be suggested by the system based on the question content when the question creator starts to type `contact`. Then the question creator selects it because it can't create a new tag because it looks good idea among many other possibilities

Comment: I have a suggestion which can't be handled on SO Meta on its own: why can't we have a tag "frozen" property/flag? Such flag would allow search by tag, but prohibit adding it to new questions (can be edited into old quetions). If it's selected for implementation, it can be simplified to just "ask mods to add this flag", and then all questions about "thing tag X refers to is dead, what to do with tag X?" can be resolved by marking X as frozen. It helps to retain old knowledge base (if I read some very old code, I may still be interested in old answers) and prevent tag misuse.

Comment: @STerliakov: So technically, I believe that is how (at least some) tag blocks work. On its own, a tag block prevents the tag from being added to new questions/articles, but it doesn't remove it from the questions/articles it's already on. (That's why the first step of requesting a tag block is generally to burninate the problem tag.) That said, I don't think there's really a precedent for blocking a tag but letting it stick around on existing questions.

Comment: @STerliakov If you read some very old code, you might have new questions, which arguably should still get the old tag.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with the recommendations in the question:

Just a tag warning along the following lines is preferable.

> This api is deprecated. Did you mean google-people-api or the product google-contacts?

I'm against closing old questions or blocking the tag entirely.

Rationale:

1. The tag may still be of historic value. Some Old APIs may still work. Some methods/techniques in answers may provide hints on using the new API.
2. Domain shared contacts API ([google-shared-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-shared-contacts), which is not deprecated) is strongly associated with google-contacts-api and AFAIK, they still use the old contacts oauth scopes
3. Users may still ask questions about migration, equivalent/comparable methods in old and new APIs.

Comment: Most questions tagged with [tag:google-contacts-api] are about the Google Contacts API and dependent Google Apps Script services. The Google Contacts API is deprecated and retired so questions that are specific about this API or the dependent services should be closed as the code in the questions and answers don't work anymore. The exception might a question asking how to do something and the answer suggested to use the API, then an ew answer could suggest to use another API.

Comment: If there are questions tagged [tag:google-contacts-api] about Google Contacts, Google Workspace Directory (shared contacts) I think that they should be retagged. Many migration questions that I have seen are very similar to "translation" questions, instead of talking about the deprecated API they should describe what the code does, sometimes the old code is just dead weight, in those cases the old code and tag of the deprecated API should not be included.

Comment: @Rubén I'm not convinced about closing such questions, as I believe they have historical value. Recently, one of my questions were closed for a similar scenario. Anyway, I want the community to decide on the consensus. So, I asked [Should reproducible questions, which becomes non-reproducible be closed and/or downvoted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426784/should-reproducible-questions-which-becomes-non-reproducible-be-closed-and-or-d). Feel free to share your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

There is retag project from 2019 [Should questions with tag [contacts] be retagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387643/1595451). This missed the fact that [google-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts) is a synonym of [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) and that there are some questions (76) [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) questions that are tagged [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api). Some aren't about the Google Contacts API.

These questions might need to be retagged, based on the above link

[android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api)  => [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[android-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-contacts).

Unless the question is really about using the **Google Contacts API**, in such a case, the question should be flagged / voted to close as no longer reproducible because the API is **deprecated and retired** as the code no longer works, nobody can have a library or service instance running on-premise, self-hosted, or alike.

P.S. The first question that I found with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) was not about programming.

Comment: Android contacts are usually Google contacts. In any case, I don't think closing "old" questions carries any good, especially just because the related api is deprecated.

Comment: @TheMaster in the case of the Google Contacts API it's deprecated **and retired**. I edited the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Just because Google retires products faster than my niece changes her hairstyle doesn't mean we should be closing all the questions about those products. What harm is produced by having a [google-contacts-api] question, that was asked several years ago, open or otherwise available? The worst that can happen is that someone copy-pastes the code without understanding and it doesn't work. Big deal. Already happens several (thousand) times a day. Maybe people will stop with the copy-pasta already.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the [previous answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426735/1595451), it was mentioned [google-shared-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-shared-contacts).

This brought to my attention that several questions tagged with [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) and/or with [google-shared-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-shared-contacts) are **also** tagged with [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) and [google-client-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-client-api).

[google-client-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-client-api) has marked as "DO NOT USE" and it has a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) -> [Confusing tag [Google-api-client]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394015/1595451)

So, things to take in mind, some people calls "API" whatever lets them interact with a Google service in one way or another. Still, Google has a lot of stuff around Google Contacts (the web and mobile apps) and Domain Directory (Google Workspace aka a platform to manage accounts and services) that use "contacts" that still works, like URL for OAuth scopes, and URLs of endpoints that belong to other APIs for which Google use a different brand. Still, askers see "contacts" and someway select [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api).

If the question is about Class ContactsApp from Google Apps Scripts they should be closed as obsolete as this code doesn't work and the migration is not easy.

Other questions using [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) should be carefully reviewed. If they are about Google Contacts API and not about something having "contacts" that misled the OP to select the [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api), and the question is specific about the API and not about making mention of it in an incidental way, it should be closed.

Questions that are wrongly using [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) should be retagged.